# Where I can find the application deployed with AWS serverless toolkit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I used serverless toolkit [serverless](https://serverless.com/) to deploy an application and all works fine.

After I logged in ASW console and I was looking for a dashboard or something where I can found and manage the deployed application.

The question is: Where I can find inside the AWS console the application deployed with serverless toolkit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Serverless framework tooling uses AWS CloudFormation for provisioning resources in the AWS cloud.  Have you checked the [AWS CloudFormation web console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home)?

Comment: Just to add more: you can also find all the deployed resources under Lambda > Applications

Comment: I found the application deployed with CodeStar in CloudFormation web console like @Gabe Hollombe said. If could help when I used serverless CLI to deploy my other app (with @ng-toolkit/serverless) I found the resource inside S3 Bucket console, but not record was present inside CloudFormation. Maybe tha stack has to be create manually.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue, you can't find the app bucket in S3 or any stack in cloudformation console because the possibility is that the location is different. Check the region of your running stack from `serverless-state.json` file and then select that region in your cloudFormation console. 
You will find your stack running here.